# Fechar uma activity e começar outra (Intersticial admob)

Tags: java, android, admob

Tenho um Intersticial admob em uma activity e quando aperto um botão coloquei as seguintes linhas de código:

```
botaoid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(mainTela.this,telaSecundaria.class));
                }



            }
        });
```

O problema é que o Intersticial está abrindo quando a telaSecundaria esta sendo fechada, como fazer para que primeiro o Intersticial abra e que quando fechado inicie a telaSecundaria?

Comment: Em qual tela esse código está sendo colocado?

Comment: @Luc no mainTela

Comment: Adicione o código da segunda tela, e também o da primeira tela, se possível.

Comment: @Luc percebi o erro, hahaahahah, sua pergunta me deu uma luz, valeu cara!

Comment: De nada, valeu! :)